# Passing multiple parameters from view to controller in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jstl

I want to pass parameter from my jsp page to controller. I found a way to do so as-
on click of-

```
<a href="ReqElement/reqTypeList.html?menuTab=CRM Setup">CRM Setup</a>
```

and in controller class-

```
@RequestMapping("/reqTypeList")
    public ModelAndView reqTypes(@ModelAttribute("reqElementSetup") ReqElementBean reqElBean, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> map,HttpSession session,@RequestParam("id") String menu) {
```

But if i want to pass multiple parameters then i have to add more @RequestParam as -

```
@RequestMapping("/reqTypeList")
public ModelAndView reqTypes(@ModelAttribute("reqElementSetup") ReqElementBean reqElBean, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> map,HttpSession session,@RequestParam("id") String id,@RequestParam("roleId") String roleid,@RequestParam("funcId") String funcid) {
```

So my question is - Is there any other convenient way to do so? Because in such above way i.e. in case of more and more parameters the size of method parameter will get increased.
I am new for Spring. Please help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know what you expect from an *other convenient way to do so*. This is the most convenient way. You specify exactly the parameters you want and those are the ones Spring gives you.

This is the right way to do it.

---

This is your problem statement

> Because in such above way i.e. in case of more and more parameters the
>   size of method parameter will get increased.

First, Spring MVC was written to make your life easier and, among other reasons, to remove as many dependencies as possible to the Servlet API.

Second, there is absolutely nothing wrong with having a lot of method parameters. You're not even calling the method yourself, Spring is and it has all the tools it needs to invoke it with the correct arguments.

Finally, the whole point of `@RequestParam` is so that you don't use `HttpServletRequest#getParameter(String)`. A method like this

```
@RequestMapping
public String someMethod(@RequestParam String param1, @RequestParam String param2) {
    // use the request parameters
}
```

is the equivalent of

```
@RequestMapping
public String someMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String param1 = request.getParameter("param1");
    String param2 = request.getParameter("param2");
    if (param1 == null) {
        throw new // some bad request exception
    }
    if (param2 == null) {
        throw new // some bad request exception
    }
    // use the request parameters
}
```

I hope you see how you have much more boilerplate, convoluted code to write. This becomes even worse if you need to add default values for missing request parameters. With Spring MVC

```
@RequestMapping
public String someMethod(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "some value") String param1)
    // use the request parameters
}
```

Without it

```
@RequestMapping
public String someMethod(HttpServletRequest request)
    String param1 = request.getParameter("param1");
    if (param1 == null) {
        param1 = "someValue";
    }
    // use the request parameters
}
```

If your API requires more request parameters, go ahead and add them, but make your life simple and use `@RequestParam` where appropriate.

Comment: yes i appreciate your response but Will's response is what i was looking for.....you both are right at your own place so i am accepting you both (but can tick to one only :( ). Thank you guys.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating more about this. Now please smile. Thanks.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I also have similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21952041/how-to-pass-multiple-values-from-the-form-to-a-controller-using-spring-mvc).. I am not able to understand what is the best way to do it as I have multiple input parameters which I need to parse it accordingly for each field.. See if you can help me there.. Thanks.. You have helped me on my couple other post as well..

Answer (score 2):

As Sotirios says, the `@RequestParam` annotation is already very convenient.

If you have a lot of request parameters, you could always specify that Spring pass the whole `HttpServletRequest` from which you can access the parameters you need.

```
@RequestMapping("/reqTypeList")
public ModelAndView reqTypes(@ModelAttribute("reqElementSetup") ReqElementBean reqElBean, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> map, HttpServletRequest request) {

    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    String roleid = request.getParameter("roleid");
    String funcid = request.getParameter("funcid");
    ...
}
```

Comment: But this still doesn't solve the multiple argument problem with an elegant way. You still have to get all arguments from the request.

Answer (score 1):

Using `request.getParameter` is not the Spring way. This is a very basic problem which was obviously thought of when Spring was made, otherwise whats the point of having a framework like this.

If you have many parameters make a DTO class with all those parameters and then you can write the controller method as below.

```
@RequestMapping("/test")

public String test(DTO dto)
{
    // your DTO has all the fields of your request parameters given that the name of the 
    //request parameters and the variables of the dto have been kept same.
}
```