# How to pass multiple values from the form to a controller using Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working with Spring MVC pattern and I am trying to make a JSP file which is like this as of now -

In the form, I have four rows, first row is just for labelling and other three rows I need to put my data in the text box. For example- for DC1, I will insert `numServers` value in the textbox, I will insert `ipaddress` value in the textbox and `hostname` value in the textbox.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Datacenter Name</td>
            <td>Number of Servers</td>
            <td>IP Address(comma separated)</td>
            <td>Host Name(comma separated)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="dc1">DC1</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="numservers" size="20"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ipaddress" size="60"></td>             
            <td><input type="text" name="hostname"  size="60"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="dc1">DC2</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="numservers" size="20"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ipaddress" size="60"></td>             
            <td><input type="text" name="hostname"  size="60"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="dc1">DC3</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="numservers" size="20"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ipaddress" size="60"></td>             
            <td><input type="text" name="hostname"  size="60"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now I am supposed to read these values after hitting the submit button as I will be typing necessary values in the textbox. I am using `RequestMapping` in my below code -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HashMap<String, String> testRequest(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<?, ?> allRequestParams) {

}
```

Initially, I was using `MultiValueMap` but I am not sure how my above input criteria will fit into this? In general, I am not sure how do I structure my input in the above method for the above use case so that I can extract all the values easily in the method?

This is the first time I started working with Spring MVC so having some difficulties..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array to spring controller like below:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public HashMap<String, String> testRequest(@RequestParam String[] numservers, @RequestParam String[] ipaddress, @RequestParam String[] hostname) {
    //By using array position you can determine each row
    //DC1 values
    String dc1_numServer = numservers[0];
    String dc1_ipaddres= ipaddress[0];
    String dc1_hostname= hostname[0];
    //DC2 values
    String dc2_numServer = numservers[1];
    String dc2_ipaddres= ipaddress[1];
    String dc2_hostname= hostname[1];
    //DC3 values
    String dc3_numServer = numservers[2];
    String dc3_ipaddres= ipaddress[2];
    String dc3_hostname= hostname[2];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.. But how would I identify, this is for `DC1` and this is for `DC2` and this if for `DC3`..? I just need to idenfity these are for DC1, these are for DC2 and these are for DC3.. So that I can parse them appropriately? And also does my JSP will also be changing for this as I don't have any object value holder?

Comment: updated answer please check, you don't need to change anything in jsp

Comment: Somehow, with the current jsp if I am hitting my URL, it is not showing any of the text box on the browser and I see exception on my eclipse concolse as servlet exception... Do you see any problem with my JSP? I think JSP has to be change, may be we need to value tag with $numservers kind of things?

Comment: what exception you are getting?

Comment: check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399347/how-to-pass-post-array-parameter-in-spring-mvc

Comment: This is the exception I am getting `Error Message : Bad Request . 400 Bad Request null`. Is it because I am using `Get` in my method instead of post?

Comment: And after using POST as well, now I get this exception `405 Method Not Allowed http method being used: GET.  Request method 'GET' not supported `. Not sure what does this mean and how to fix it? Any thoughts?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48165/discussion-between-ssh-and-ramesh-k)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to define a model to hold this entire information:

```
public class Datacenter {

    private String name;
    private String ipAddress;
    private String hostName;
    private String numServers;
    // Add getters and setters..
}


public class Datacenters {
    private List<Datacenter> datacenters;
    //Getters and setters..
}
```

Now, you will have to change your form to cleanly bind to this data structure in the following way:

```
    <tr>
        <td><label for="dc1">DC1</label></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="datacenters[0].name" value="DC1"/>
        <td><input type="text" name="datacenter[0].numServers" size="20"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="datacenter[0].ipAddress" size="60"></td>             
        <td><input type="text" name="datacenter[0].hostName"  size="60"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="dc1">DC2</label></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="datacenters[1].name" value="DC2"/>
        <td><input type="text" name="datacenter[1].numServers" size="20"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="datacenter[1].ipAddress" size="60"></td>             
        <td><input type="text" name="datacenter[1].hostName"  size="60"></td>
    </tr>
```

With this change you can simply bind this model to your Controller in this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testRequest(DataCenters dataCenters) {
    //.. process request
}
```

That's it, Spring should bind everything for you.

Comment: Thanks Biju.. In your data holder class, there should be only one public class correct? Currently if I am using as it is, it is giving me compilation exception

Comment: Yes, this is just a quick and dirty sample code @SSH, it requires cleanup - you have to add getters and setter, move the classes to individual files etc.

Comment: Sure.. And also after making the changes in the JSP file as you have mentioned in your suggestion, when I am hitting my url like this `http://127.0.0.1:8080/dataweb/test`, it always go to my `testRequest` method without loading the JSP page first for me so `dataCenters` is always null for the first time and then after that, I can see my JSP page on the browser and after that If I hit submit, I see this error - `Error Message : Request method 'POST' not supported . 405 Method Not Allowed http method being used: POST. Request method 'POST' not supported`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: If you can place your code in github, I can try and fix the code and send you a pull request, let me know, difficult to figure out what could be going wrong from the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The Status 405 occurs because your listener for the method is a GET.
You need to change it to POST so that it'll accept a post.